# Best VBA Approach in Access for Median of a Dataset

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, median

I am a novice in access and VBA. I have a function that I use to calculate the median. The current function acts as a Domain function and uses all data to calculate the median rather than the dataset that makes up the rest of the query/report. I would like to know how to modify this code or a better approach to find the median of dataset used to create the report.

```
Option Compare Database 
Option Explicit 



Function DMedian(tName As String, fldName As String) As Single 
  Dim MedianDB As DAO.Database 
  Dim ssMedian As DAO.Recordset 
  Dim RCount As Integer, i As Integer, x As Double, y As Double, _ 
      OffSet As Integer 
  Set MedianDB = CurrentDb() 
  Set ssMedian = MedianDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT [" & fldName & _ 
            "] FROM [" & tName & "] WHERE [" & fldName & _ 
            "] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [" & fldName & "];") 
  'NOTE: To include nulls when calculating the median value, omit 
  'WHERE [" & fldName & "] IS NOT NULL from the example. 
  ssMedian.MoveLast 
  RCount% = ssMedian.RecordCount 
  x = RCount Mod 2 
  If x <> 0 Then 
     OffSet = ((RCount + 1) / 2) - 2 
     For i% = 0 To OffSet 
        ssMedian.MovePrevious 
    Next i 
    DMedian = ssMedian(fldName) 
 Else 
     OffSet = (RCount / 2) - 2 
     For i = 0 To OffSet 
        ssMedian.MovePrevious 
     Next i 
     x = ssMedian(fldName) 
     ssMedian.MovePrevious 
     y = ssMedian(fldName) 
     DMedian = (x + y) / 2 
  End If 
  If Not ssMedian Is Nothing Then 
     ssMedian.Close 
     Set ssMedian = Nothing 
  End If 
  Set MedianDB = Nothing 
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to calculating the median against a custom report that you have created, then simply save your query and pass the query name in to 'tname' instead of a table name.

Comment: Interesting answer, Matt. I never though about it from that angle. I tried to use the query that the report is based off of. Dmedian("qrySearch","SoldPrice") The report itself is based on the same query. I get an error on this part of the code: Set ssMedian = MedianDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT [" & fldName & _ "] FROM [" & tName & "] WHERE [" & fldName & _ "] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [" & fldName & "];")

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving?
I notice that the query is called "qrysearch", it's not a parameter query is it?

Comment: I'm thinking it is a parameter query. The criteria field finds the value of a textbox in a form using LIKE. The error is too few parameters.

Comment: Yep, that's what the problem is then, if you want to run the median function against it, you will have to dynamically populate a query with the parameter already saved so that it doesn't attempt to ask for it when you run this function.

Comment: Thank you, Matt. I'm not exactly sure how to dynamically populate the query with the parameter already saved. My situation is this: I have a form "Search" that collects values from textboxes and runs them in the query "qrySearch" The query is the controlSource for my report "Breakdown". I hope this sheds light on my situation. Thanks again!!!

Comment: At the moment, your query likely has references in it to the form textboxes, what you would do instead is rebuild your query using the querydef method e.g: Currentdb.QueryDefs("qrySearch").SQL = "SELECT Field 1, 2, 3 FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 = Text1 AND Field2 = Text2" etc. Then your query would have these values saved and in effect not be a parameter query anymore.

Comment: Matt, Thank you very much. You are correct. I decided to run my query without the parameters involved. When no parameters are involved, the VBA code functions exactly as intended. This solves the issue I was having. I have decided to rework my search query to accomodate this methodology. Thanks again for your help!!!